# When do I use "мой" и "моя"

Tags: грамматика, узус

I have been learning Russian for a year now. I took a trip to somewhere where there are many Russian speaking peoples. I realized that I use мойи моя incorrectly. Can someone please help me.

Comment: It will be better if you add an example of incorrect use, so we can see where you make the mistake.

Answer (score 6):

The difference is in [grammatical gender](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_gender).

**Мой** is used for **masculine** objects:

> мой дом, мой планшет, мой любимый (мужчина).

**Моя** is used for **feminine** objects:

> моя машина, моя сеть, моя любимая (женщина).

You haven't mentioned but as there are three genders in Russian language there is also **моё** that is used for **neuter gender** objects:

> моё окно, моё видение.

P.S.: As you may have noticed all of them are used for animate and inanimate objects.

Comment: For beginners: a few masculine nouns end in -a or -я, such as names of some male relatives папа (dad), дядя (uncle), дедушка (grandfather), and for these you have to use мой just as with all other masculine nouns.

Comment: ...and nouns ending in -ь can be masculine or feminine and their gender has to be learned with each word.

Comment: It is great that mention the 3rd case, +1 for completeness.